# Record user's wrong input url in php

Tags: php, web-services

I have a question for how to record a manually entered wrong URl. The scenario is: a user wants to visit `mywebsite.com/page.php`, but incorrectly entered `mywebsite.com/page2.php`, which does not exist.

My question is: how to record the user's input `page2.php`?

Note: I am not asking how to redirect.

Comment: It will get recorded in your web server log file.

Comment: You can record all access instead into database then filter the data later.

Answer (score 1):

Use htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /getError.php
```

And in getError.php get current URL

```
echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // Save This
```